# Grails: Use regex with filter

Tags: regex, filter, grails-2.4

I have two URL's addresses which I have filter for everyone of them:

```
all(uri: '/api/first/**')
{
    before =
}
all(uri: '/api/second/**')
{
    before =
}
```

I want to write just one filter for both.
So I have tried to write a filter with regex:

```
all(uri: '\\/api\\/(first|second)\\/.*', regex: true)
{
    before =
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I have tried many ways ('**' / '.*' / invert: true)
But didn't succeed.

Does someone know where the mistake and what the right way to write the filter?

Thanks...

Comment: Perhaps, you overescaped the expression. Try just `'/api/(first|second)/.*'`

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `find` instead of `uri`: `all(regex: true, find: '/api/(first|second)/.*')`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#filters), `uri` is an [ant path](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) and does not support regular expressions. You need to rely on `find`:

```
all(regex: true, find: '/api/(first|second)/.*')
{
   before = {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you really need to escape `/`, this symbol is not a special regex operator, and only must be escaped when it is used as a regex delimiter, and here, no regex delimiters are used.

Comment: I came to the filter from many other URLs. I need to come just from the both addresses

Comment: Maybe you need to anchor the regex, like `'^/api/(first|second)/.*'`. Please update your question with more data.